# How to use airport panel information on sectional chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, chart-supplement

In the Chart Supplement, the airport information includes the chart on which the airport is located. It also includes a *panel* on the chart where the airport is located. How can I use this panel information? Sectional charts don't appear to have panels.

Here is the airport information for San Francisco International:
[image]

I understand that *San Francisco* stands for San Francisco Sectional Chart and *H-3B* and *L-2F* are for the IFR charts, but how can I use the *3B* and *A* information?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is nothing in the front matter that would explain what those mean.  I do know from that document "A" indicates that airport is on an area chart.  The others appear to be a helicopter chart of TAC chart.  I do not know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to @JWalters's answer:

**L-2F, 3B** is one group, and it refers to the "Enroute Low Chart Number(s) and Panel Identification",$^1$ that is:

- L-2F, *and*
- L-3B.

Since you are aware of the L-2F, here's the L-3B:

[image]
Source: [skyvector.com](https://skyvector.com/?ll=37.64694911326959,-121.83405089035548&chart=403&zoom=6)

---

$^1$ Interagency Air Committee (IAC) Specifications, IAC 8, [faa.gov](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/iac/), § 3.1.5.2.7

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer. I have not succeeded so far in finding an answer regarding the "3B". However, the "A" is addressed in the Chart Supplement.

According to the front matter in the Chart Supplement, the "A" indicates that the airport is depicted on an Area Enroute Chart, in this case on the SFO Area chart. 
See the following quote from the Chart Supplement's Airport/Facility Directory Legend:

> Charts refer to the Sectional Chart and Low and High Altitude Enroute Chart and panel on which the airport or facility is depicted. Pacific Enroute Chart will be indicated by P. **Area Enroute Charts will be indicated by A.** Helicopter Chart depictions will be indicated as COPTER. IFR Gulf of Mexico West and IFR Gulf of Mexico Central will be referenced as GOMW and GOMC.